# Pro Micro don't receiving anything via Serial1

Tags: arduino, serial-port, baud-rate

I'm using Pro Micro (16 MHz, 5V) board and I want to read serial data which are coming from external UART device (for a test I connect TX1 and RX0 pins to FTDI cable which is connect to computer). Baudrate is 115200. Chosed board in Arduino software is SparkFun Pro Micro, 16 MHz, 5V.

If I send any text from Pro Micro to computer, I see this text normal on computer (Putty), for ex. Hello World. If I type any text in Putty, I don't see anything in Serial monitor. It looks like that Pro Micro has problems with receiving string via Serial1. I used oscilloscope and I put probe on RX0 (everything looked ok) and I'm sure that data were send from computer (via FTDI) without problems.

```
    setup()
    {
      Serial1.begin(115200);
      Serial.begin(115200);
      delay(5000);
      Serial1.begin("Hello World");
    }
    void loop()
    {
      if (Serial1.available()) {
      Serial.write(Serial1.read());
      }
    }
```

I tried to use lower baudrate (57600, 38400, ...) but nothing changed.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong...please help me! Thank you!

Comment: are you sure you want to write to `Serial` the byte recieved on `Serial1` ? if you have seen "hello world" in your terminal you must be connected to that serial line